# Warning: Couldn't coerce the `start` argument to a date string with format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to understand the warning messages as I run the APP below. The following messages appear:

```
Warning: Couldn't coerce the `start` argument to a date string with format yyyy-mm-dd
Warning: Couldn't coerce the `end` argument to a date string with format yyyy-mm-dd
```

These messages appear is due the `start` and `end` are as `NA` in the `daterange`, but why a `WARNING` message? Is there any way to remove this message? I enter both as `NA` as I would not want any dates to be selected when running the APP.

Code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-22","2021-10-22","2021-10-29","2021-10-29")), 
                       Week = c("Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')
                                 
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date1))

  })
  
  observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    Test <- filter(data(),
                   date1 %in% days | 
                     date2 %in% days)
        meanTest<-Test%>%
      group_by(Week,Category)%>%
      summarize(mean(time))
    
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are forcing the start and end dates to be `NA`.  Instead, define a start and end in the past, and don't define `NA` for start and end in an observer - as shown below.

```
Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-22","2021-10-22","2021-10-29","2021-10-29")), 
                       Week = c("Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput("daterange0", "Period you want to see Now:",
                 start  = "2009-01-01",
                 end    = "2020-12-31",
                 min   = min(Test$date1))
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output, session) { 
  # observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange0",start = NA, end = NA)})
})
```

Comment: What if you want the default date(s) to be blank to the user?